# At least probability with high n and m

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I know that "at least"-probabilities can be calculated as:  $p(\ge m) = 1 - p(<m)$ and for small values of $m$, say 2, this becomes $p(\ge 2) = 1 - (p(0) + p(1))$.

But now I am given a problem where I am asked to calculate the probability of at least 10 successes out of 70 trials. I doubt that I should do this by brute-force, calculating $1 - \sum_{i=0}^{9}{p(i)}$.

In the given problem there is a fixed probability of success per trial of $\frac{1}{5}$.

Are there alternative ways of calculating the "at least" / "at most" probabilities in such a scenario?

Comment: It's easy to do this particular calculation exactly.  Well, "easy" with mechanical help, of course.  Otherwise, just use the normal approximation (for which you will also need a computer, or at least a table).

Comment: Okay, mechanical help is not an option in this case. Maybe I'm given a table, need to check on that..

Comment: You can't do much with the binomial distribution without a calculator or a table.  Of course, it is easy to write the answer as a sum of binomial coefficients, but you won't be able to evaluate that sum by hand in a sensible amount of time.

Comment: Finding a cumulative probability without a calculator or some online program is much harder (especially since there is such a large number of trials ($70$)). Your best bet is to use the binomial theorem and pascals triangle: 

$$(p+q)^{n}={n \choose 0}q^{n}p^{0}+{n \choose 1}q^{n-1}p^{1}+{n \choose 2}q^{n-2}p^{2}+\cdots +{n \choose n-1}q^{1}p^{n-1}+{n \choose n}q^{0}p^{n} = 1$$